# C++ files not being saved permanently

Tags: file

I just made a simple program that basically saves number into the program that the user inputs and save it to a file called data.txt and this value is **cumulative** so when the user comes again and input another number the old value will be called for some operation you will see in the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
ifstream input;
ofstream output, invoice;

// initializations
int total = 0, x = 0;
double pay = 0, rate = 0.1008;
char choice = ' ';


// time code
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time (&rawtime);
timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
// timecode 


// Open data.txt to get total
invoice.open("invoice.txt", fstream::out|fstream::app);
input.open("data.txt");
if(input.is_open()){
    input>>total;
}else{
    cout<<"Error file hasn't been opened!";
    return 0;
}
input.close();
// Modify data.txt
output.open("data.txt");
if(output.is_open()){
    mistake1:
    mistake2:
    cout<<"\t\t\tTotal hours from last time:"<<total<<endl;
    cout<<"\tDate: "<<asctime(timeinfo);
    cout<<"Enter hours: ";
    cin>>x;
    if(x<=total){
        cout<<"Error! re-enter the hours (they can't be less than or equal to "<<total<<"):"<<endl<<endl;
        goto mistake1;
    }
    cout<<"The value you've entered is "<<x<<", correct? (answer with Y or N):"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice == 'N' || choice == 'n'){
        goto mistake2;
    }
    if(total == 0){
        total=x;
        pay = x*rate;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"\tDate: "<<asctime(timeinfo);
        cout<<endl<<"\t\t*Information*"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"\tTotal hours used: "<<x<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"\tYou have to pay ( "<<pay<<" $) this month."<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------";
        invoice<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        invoice<<"\tDate: "<<asctime(timeinfo);
        invoice<<endl<<"\t\t*Information*"<<endl<<endl;
        invoice<<"\tTotal hours used: "<<x<<endl<<endl;
        invoice<<"\tYou have to pay ( "<<pay<<" $) this month."<<endl;
        invoice<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    }else{
        pay = (x-total)*rate;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"\tDate: "<<asctime(timeinfo);
        cout<<endl<<"\t\t*Information*"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"\tTotal hours used: "<<x<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"\tYou have to pay ( "<<pay<<" $) this month."<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"\tYou have used the AC "<<x-total<<" hour/s this month!"<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------";
        invoice<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        invoice<<"\tDate: "<<asctime(timeinfo);
        invoice<<endl<<"\t\t*Information*"<<endl<<endl;
        invoice<<"\tTotal hours used: "<<x<<endl<<endl;
        invoice<<"\tYou have to pay ( "<<pay<<" $) this month."<<endl<<endl;
        invoice<<"\tYou have used the AC "<<x-total<<" hour/s this month!"<<endl;
        invoice<<"----------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        total=x;
    }
    output<<total;
}
output.close();
cout<<endl<<endl<<"Enter any key to exit or press the X button...";
cin>>choice;
return 0;
}
```

The code is fine and working properly but here is where the problem comes.
[This (hours) value is called from the data.txt at first, it is defaulted to zero so everything is still fine (look at the date and time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hVkw.png)

[Now I checked data.txt and the value is saved there as wanted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Okk.png)

[I reopened the program after seconds and everything is saved as wanted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyH8I.png)

[Then after few seconds I opened again (it is weird sometimes it takes long to do this (hours) and sometimes it takes (seconds) ) the value was gone and data.txt is empty it is not even zero just empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptAjO.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this weird problem :S?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the correct openmode for all `open("data.txt")` calls. Just add `fstream::in` for `input.open("data.txt"). It should work.

The reason is that everytime your code opens the data.txt file, you are first opening to read the data in. And then you are opening to write the data out. You need to handle the first case when the file does not exist in the input operation. And your code should work.

Comment: This is what it does, i.imgur.com/lYgWHTV.png I want it to like overwrite it so every time the user enters a value the old one is gone and replaced with the new one, here is what i did i opened the program the first time and put 25 and then opened it again and put and it became 2550 i.imgur.com/UcN6kbZ.png, and thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide file open mode for this operation. For example, in your case it would be

```
output.open ("data.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

This should work as per your expectations.

Comment: This is what it does, https://i.imgur.com/lYgWHTV.png I want it to like overwrite it so every time the user enters a value the old one is gone and replaced with the new one, here is what i did i opened the program the first time and put 25 and then opened it again and put and it became 2550 https://i.imgur.com/UcN6kbZ.png, and thanks!